# Ionic 4 native plugin not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am facing a problem with Ionic 4 native plugins. I have installed *ionic 4 Cordova native plugin* *"Geolocation"* but when I run the app into my iOS or Android device it's showing to me a blank white screen and nothing happening.

`app.module.ts` code:

```
import {
  Geolocation
} from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen, ** Geolocation ** , {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: IonicRouteStrategy
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

`Home.ts` code:

```
import {
  Geolocation
} from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}
```

**I don't know why it's happening. But It's working on Ionic 3 project.**

Anyone can give me any idea why it's happening and what I did wrong.

Comment: Any errors? Could be an issue with rxjs versions. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626937/ionic-4-native-plugin-geolocation-gives-me-module-not-found-error-cant-resol

Comment: Same here with any native plugin. It seems to be an injection problem inside the constructor. Try removing 'private geolocation: Geolocation' and the app should run properly. But without the plugin... :/

Comment: Another info : it seems we now have to add the /ngx suffix to the Ionic plugin import path. But it can't be found on my computer. Wrong Ionic package installed ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the solution :

- open your **package.json** and update `@ionic-native/geolocation` to **5.0.0-beta.14** (same as `@ionic-native/core`)
- npm install
- update all your imports : `import {Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';` (in app.module.ts and in your component.ts file)

Comment: Man, you saved my day :D

Comment: if I update @ionic-native/core to 5.0.0-beta.14, what other difficulties I could face?? bcz my remaining plugins are in 3.x or 4.x version??

Comment: currently I am having 
@ionic-native/core: 4.6.0 &
@ionic-native/camera: ^5.0.0
my camera is not working

Comment: @ionic-native/core should have the same version as plugins: npm install @ionic-native/core@5.0.0-beta.24 --save. Same for all plugins.