# Ionic 4 native plugin geolocation gives me "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable'"

Tags: angular, geolocation, rxjs, ionic-native, ionic4

I'm trying to use ionic native plugin `geolocation` in `ionic 4` but I got a this error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/@ionic-native/geolocation/index.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in
>   'C:\Projects\ionic\prayers\node_modules\@ionic-native\geolocation'

this is my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.9",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "@ionic/ng-toolkit": "1.0.0",
    "@ionic/schematics-angular": "1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "rxjs": "6.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
```

this is the code I used:-

app.module.ts

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
...
NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen, Geolocation,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

home.ts

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
...
constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have `rxjs 6.2.2` installed where importing statements are changed.

The stable ionic-native is still using [rxjs 5.x](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/package.json).

You can check the migration guide [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md).

You can either use [rxjs-compat](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#backwards-compatibility)

```
npm i rxjs-compat --save
```

Or go back to 5.x version.

Another option is to update `@ionic-native/geolocation` version to **5.0.0-beta14**

like your other ionic-native plugins since according to the [package.json](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/v5/package.json), it should be using rxjs 6.x

```
npm i --save @ionic-native/geolocation@5.0.0-beta.14
```

Comment: i am having a problem with native-Geocoder, so i guess its the same problem.. how do i know the new beta versions of native api?

Comment: you need to check their repo and see if they have upgraded rxjs.. otherwise you will need to use the older version till then

Comment: npm i --save @ionic-native/geolocation@5.0.0-beta.14
worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and when upgrading `Geolocation` to `5.0.0-beta.14` I also had to update the import path to:
`import { Geolocation } from "@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx";`

OBS: For other imports like `UniqueDeviceID` I also had to add the `/ngx` suffix to the import path.
I think this suffix is required due to version 6 of Angular.

Comment: Yes in Ionic 4 documentation they stated that "/ngx" path is needed for angular since ionic now support other frameworks, but they gived us the npm command to install the old version of geolocation which doesn't have "/ngx" ...